# Is substrate based blockchain compatible with solana?

Tags: substrate, parity

Recently someone told me about Solana. I went throgh their website https://solana.com/. I just wanted to know whether substrate pallet is compatible with solana. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Different bridges are currently being built like Wormhole, but most efforts are concentrated on SOL <> ETH at the moment. For a good reason, as most liquidity is on Ethereum.

Polkadot support is in the plans though, as per a discussion I had yesterday with a core Wormhole developer.